# How can I load data into Google Cloud SQL from Google Big Query?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I have json files flowing in to Google Cloud Storage and then a process setup to flatten them out and load into a table in Google Big Query. I'm wondering if it is possible to setup a sync between the Google Big Query table and a table in Google Cloud SQL so I don't have to write additional code to write the data to two places. Is this possible?

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454569/export-from-google-bigquery-into-cloudsql

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I mis-read the question. BigQuery supports the API to export to CSV file and Cloud SQL also supports the CSV import, and the default CSV format that bigquery and Cloud SQL uses are compatible.

Original answer: There is no automatic sync setup for this. You need to write a small program to retrieve the data from Cloud SQL and load it to Big Query (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery)

Comment: He wants data in Google Cloud sql from BigQuery!

Comment: @tianzhou: For you answer, Cloud SQL to big Query is also not quite possible as it only allows 1,000 inserts per day per table.