# How to delete cloudsql mysql records through bigquery. Federated query gives error "Failed to get query schema from MySQL server"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, federated

Hello google cloud and bigquery experts :-)

I have a cloudsql mysql database and a BigQuery database in GCP
I need to delete certain records in the cloudsql mysql database using mechanism akin to bigquery federated queries.
for example see below (does not work offcourse :-( )

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("uca-proddev-devops.us-east1.uca-useast-cloudsql-conn", " DELETE from inventory. cloud_object_events where cloud_object_id in (SELECT cloud_object_id from inventory.cloud_objects where date_created <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY);”);
```

This gives me an error

```
Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY
Failed to get query schema from MySQL server. Error: MysqlErrorCode(0):  at [3:15]
```

I checked the Cloud SQL federated queries documentation at (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries). It clearly mentions that "external_database_query (string): is a **read-only query** in the external database's SQL dialect (MySQL or PostgreSQL).
So it seems like I cannot use federated queries mechanism directly to delete records from cloudsql using a criteria based on data in bigquery.

Exporting data from BigQuery and importing in cloudsql for forming a delete query is too rigorous.
Is there a more convenient mechanism that would allow me to delete from cloudsql based on data in BigQuery.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36464054/11866104 "If you need more granular control, you can use the BigQuery API to perform the query, fetch the results, connect to the Cloud SQL instance and insert the data."

Comment: If you use "Select * from inventory" instead  "DELETE from inventory" does this works for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete/update data with Cloud SQL federated table. You can only read in Cloud SQL.

You need to implement your own process elsewhere (Cloud Functions, Cloud Run,...)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your response @guillaume blaquiere